# Action Mailer failed assertion. Can someone help me understand why my email.to assertion fails to match?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a broken ActionMailer::Base test that at the moment confounds me. Perhaps I am not seeing what the error is but when I reach my assertion that checks that an email's to: field is correctly shown, I receive the error in question. Below is a snippet of my code. I am unsing MiniTest::Spec::Test with Factory Girl. Below is my Factory Girl code and test condition. I have outlined the problem areas and have illustrated what the conditions would print out on the console.

```
 describe PostsController do
  let(:forum) { create(:forum) }
  let(:user) { create(:account) }
  let(:admin) { create(:admin) }
  let(:topic) { create(:topic) }
  let(:post_object) { create(:post) }
  before { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear }

   #code ------------

  it 'create action: user2 replying to user1 receives 
    a creation email while user1 receives a reply email' do

   login_as user
   assert_difference('ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size', 2) do
     post :create, topic_id: post_object.topic.id, post: { body: 
          'Post reply gets sent to User 1. Post creation gets sent to User 2' }
   end
   email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries

  # -----debugging area ----------

  puts email.first.to     'user1@gmail.com'
  puts email.last.to      'user2@gmail.com'
  puts email.map(&:to)    'user1@gmail.com, user2@gmail.com'

  # ------debugging area --------

  #-------failing test ----------

  email.first.to.must_equal post_object.topic.account.email
  Expected 'comesoutofnowhereuser@gmail.com, Actual: user1@gmail.com'

  #------failing test -----------

  email.first.subject.must_equal 'Someone has responded to your post'
  email.last.to.must_equal user.email
  email.last.subject.must_equal 'Post successfully created'
  must_redirect_to topic_path(post_object.topic.id)
end
```

I don't know why crazyuser@gmail.com is to be expected. I'm wondering if there is any change after the assert_difference block but I've also tried running puts and debugger statements in the block and I get the same results. Nothing changes coming out of assert_difference. Some help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`.to` should give you an Array of email addresses, so test that the email is included in the array with `must_include`:

```
email.last.to.must_include user.email
```

Comment: Hey infused. Thanks for the reply, the test that has been breaking on me was email.last.to etc. not email.first.to. I tried you're suggestion with
email.first.to.must_include post_object.topic.account.email but its a completely different email. Still befuddled....... still working on it.

Comment: I meant the problem area was email.first.last not email.last.to. Been staring at this forever.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem was that my factories were off. The associations among my factory data were being dynamically generated on the fly to different data. Overriding the factory data solved this problem.